# Issues with centering text vertically in HTML

Tags: html, alignment, center

I understand this type of question has been posted many times, but I cannot seem to figure out what my issue is.  I  have a block of text and I want to center it vertically on the left side of the page.  I do not want to use heavy padding to center the text.  I want it centered vertically if the visitor changes with window height.

I have a block of text:

```
<div class="welcome">
    <p>Testing Stuff</p> <br /> <br />  
    <p>Testing Stuff</p> <br /> <br />
    <p>Testing Stuff</p> <br /> <br />
    <p>Testing Stuff</p>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS for *welcome*

```
.welcome {
position: absolute;
top:50%;
display: table;
vertical-align: middle;
padding-left: 50px;
font-family: 'Helvetica-Light';
font-size: 40px;
}

.welcome p{
display: inline;
vertical-align: middle;
padding: 10px;
background: black;
color: white;
opacity: 0.7;
white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Currently the top:50% sets the text starting at 50% but I need the center of the text block to be at 50%, not start at 50%.

Help please.

Comment: What are the `<br>` tags for?

Comment: can you add align : center for .welcome  and see if it works

Comment: Spacing between the paragraph lines.  I am putting a background on the text and I need more space so the backgrounds don't overlap.  Is there a better way than <br> tags?

Comment: Align does not come up in my auto-complete so I am assuming it is a deprecated tag.

Comment: You have css. Use it. Give the `.welcome p` tags `padding-left` and `padding-right`. Also, `align: center` only works for *horizontal* alignment and it's not deprecated. Vertical is a bit trickier.

Comment: I do not want to use heavy padding.  I want it vertically centered if the visitor adjusts the size of the window.

Comment: Heavy padding? What you're trying to do with the `br` tags (intentionally chew whitespace with markup) is antiquated and is what css is designed to do in practice.

Comment: Do you want the first element to start in the middle or the four elements to be centered all together?

Comment: Dim 13i, great question.  I want all the elements to be centered together.

Comment: Alright, it's centered in this fiddle, but it's not quite there yet: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/CuUgV/

Comment: Should you give it some height?

Comment: can you elaborate? if you just want to center it, use text-align: center; in your welcome div

Comment: Everyone (and @kennypu), Zachary is looking for *vertical*, not *horizontal*, alignment. Up-down centering, not left-right.

Comment: @JaredFarrish in that case, isn't the fiddle you posted good enough? it does look vertically centered.

Comment: The fiddle is very close.  Thanks a lot @JaredFarrish, you should post it as an answer.

Comment: Not quite; it's not just like what was posted (the white gaps between "cells"), and I don't quite like the transient `div.row` being there. Problem is, the `display: table` approach sorta needs that extra layer for the `display: table-cell` to serve as the middling (literally and figuratively) stand-in. I haven't figured out a more elegant, less verbose approach though.

Comment: @JaredFarrish when I put that code in, it is off center about 10-15 pixels.  Also, the margin: auto in concert with the padding:50px moves it out into the center of the page.  Removing the margin: auto sends it back to where I want it with no other side effects.

Comment: Do you want the `.welcome` element to span the entire `100%` page width, or is it not meant to span the entire page width? (Also, the `margin: auto` was a previous test I forgot to remove. However, see my posted answer for what I figured out using that.)

Comment: I just want the block of text vertically centered.  It should not span the entire page width.  Sorry, I'm new to HTML/CSS so I don't know much.  Whatever makes it work, I think you are closest to figuring it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still checking this out, but here's one way:

**HTML**

```
<div class="welcome">
  <div class="row">
      <p>Testing Stuff</p> 
      <p>Testing Stuff</p>
      <p>Testing Stuff</p>
      <p>Testing Stuff</p>
    </div>
</div>​
```

**CSS**

```
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.welcome {
    height: 100%;
    width: 1px;
    display: table;
    padding-left: 50px;
    margin: auto;
    font-family: 'Helvetica-Light';
    font-size: 30px;
}
.welcome .row {
    display: table-cell;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.welcome .row p {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 10px;
    background: black;
    color: white;
    opacity: 0.7;
}​
```

Note the use of `100%` on the `html, body` lines, which allows you to use `margin: auto` and `height: 100%` on the `.welcome` element. I fixed the white gaps (due to the "whitespace" interpreted within the `display: table-cell` block, ie, those `p` tags are on separate lines, hence the gaps.

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/CuUgV/3/

Answer (score 0):

I did this with some jQuery, hope this is what you want: [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Dim13i/K7fyR/)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="welcome">
    <div class="container">
        <p>Testing Stuff</p> <br /> <br />  
        <p>Testing Stuff</p> <br /> <br />
        <p>Testing Stuff</p> <br /> <br />
        <p>Testing Stuff</p>
    </div>
</div>​
```

**CSS:**

```
.welcome {
    position: absolute;
    padding-left: 50px;
    font-family: 'Helvetica-Light';
    font-size: 40px;
    height: 100%;
}

.welcome p{
    display: inline;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 10px;
    background: black;
    color: white;
    opacity: 0.7;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
}​
```

**JS:**

```
$(function() {
    var containerHeight = $('.container').height();
    $('.container').css({'margin-top': -containerHeight/2});
});​
```

**UPDATE** without jQuery: **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Dim13i/K7fyR/1/)**

Comment: jQuery? You don't need jQuery for this.

Comment: Just to set the margin-top, but still, this is just one solution ;)

Comment: Can you please tell me where to paste that JS code snippet?  I am new to all this web stuff so I don't even know where to put.

Comment: Include this in the `<head>`: `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>` and then after the `<div class="welcome"></div>`, or at the end of the file: `<script>[CODE INSIDE]</script>`.

Comment: Oh come on. @ZacharyHunt does not need to *add a whole library* and separate code to do this. It's overkill, man. But, yes, it is one way to do it. `:s`

Comment: It depends if he's gonna use it for other things. Of course it's not necessary only for this problem, but it's still useful for a lot of other things. And for new guys it's also easier to work with.

Comment: Well, another anti-pattern is that jQuery is the best thing to learn first; basic Javascript skills should be first. I see a lot of crazy ideas on this site that I attribute to a) "jQuery fixes/enhances/walks the dog better", when more simple and direct approaches are better than most script approaches in general; and b), it adds complexity at a time when fundamentals are much more critical. You can do all kinds of whacky stuff with jQuery (and Javascript), but it should not be the first thing anyone reaches for. Then it becomes a crutch and obscures real meaning beneath a lot of useless code.

Comment: I do agree with you about everything you say but I think that for what he's asking this is the easiest solution. It's just about setting the margin-top, but I need to know the exact size of the `.container`. This way we don't care how many paragraphs he puts inside the `.container` it will always be centered vertically.

Comment: Well, I took a look at your fiddle and realized I missed the true impact of the `br` elements @ZacharyHunt had in his markup; when I removed it, I didn't actually preview the as-is code. So I need to redo that in my fiddle. But, your centering is just *slightly* off (on the top), maybe `2-3px`. But, let me see if I can get the same result using the same thing without Javascript...

Comment: @JaredFarrish I've updated my answer and added at the end a link to a versione without jQuery! ;) Anyway I think that using Javascript helps a lot here, it's difficult to get the right result only by using CSS.

Comment: I thought my approach was reasonable and only breaks down in IE7 (`display: table` are not supported, nor is `display: inline-block`, which would be useful here for the `P` tags). So I have to figure that out.